# Show Form2 7seconds delayed after Form1 close

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two forms in my application, form2 is shown on clicking a button in the form1. but i need a **delay of 7 seconds between form1's close and form2's show** for that i wrote the following code:

```
   Public Class Form1
      Dim i As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      i = 0
      Me.Close()
      Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
      i += 1
      If i = 7 Then
      Form1.Show()
      End If
    End Sub
  End Class
```

But it does not give me the result. form2 not shown at all. what was the mistake i had made in the code? can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're closing form 1, which contains the timer, before it's finished running.  Try moving the timer and code to form 2, keeping it hidden for 7 secs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there's no active form left in a Windows Forms application, the application will quit. Therefore, you might want to hide the main form instead of closing it:

```
Me.Hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think no need of unnecessary declaration for time delay because you can simply set it on your `timer control` itself

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 7000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

or

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 7000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```